# Hotswapped NVMe drives show in lspci but not in lsblk

Tags: linux, rhel, nvme

I'm messing around with NVMe hotswap on my Oracle X8-2L.  I have a number of NVMe drives that are connected to the server before boot and then a number of NVMe drives that will be connected after the server is booted.  Right after boot I do a lsblk and see all the drives connected at the time of boot as expected.  At this point I connect the hotswap drives and do a "echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/rescan".  After the rescan I do another "lsblk" but I only see the NVMe drives that were connected to the system at boot up, the drives connected after boot are missing.

However I do a "lspci -v | grep -i nvme" and I see the extra hotswap connected drives but they show up with no "Kernel driver in use"

See below, the nvme drives that show both "Kernel driver in use: nvme" and "Kernel modules: nvme" are the drives connected at boot up, the drives with only "kernel modules: nvme" are the drives connected after boot up (see 0000:cf:00.0 vs 0000:ce:00.0)

[image]

It would seem like all I would need to do is get the driver working for these drives, they show up as nvme drives, the kernel sees them as nvme drives, I cant figure out why the driver is not getting loaded for them.  I thought doing a bind on the device would attach the driver (I've not spent a whole lot of time in this area so I could be wrong) I've tried to do a

"echo 0000:cf:00.0 > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/nvme/bind" but it returns a "bash: echo: write error: No such device"

Looking in /sys/bus/pci/devices I see the device present

[image]
Not sure what the next step to attempt would be.